# Can I enclose a flatlist inside a webview somehow?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

In my mainscreen App I am rendering a flatlist of articles , I need to change the code so that the urls open inside the App(like webview) . Does anyone know how can I modify the following code ?

```
render() {
if (this.state.refreshing) {
  return (
    <View style={styles.refreshing}>
      <ActivityIndicator />
    </View>
  )
} else {
return (
  <List>  
    <FlatList
    data={this.state.articles}
    renderItem={({ item }) => <Article article={item} />}
    keyExtractor={item => item.url}
    refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
    onRefresh={this.handleRefresh.bind(this)}
    />
  </List>

  );
 }
 }
```